# iPhone: Find Button at Custom Row

Tags: iphone

(Have a question...A have a table view xib and a custom row xib which I use in Table View...In Custom row xib I put 2 buttons (Button1 and Button2) by Interface Builder...So when I run my app a have a Table View with a lot of rows..and in every row I have 2 buttons...What I need is when I press Button1 in current row, to set Button2 Highlighted in the same row...

I just simply created an IBAction to do that:

```
  - (IBAction)buttonTouchIn:(id)sender{
     if (sender == self.button1) {
         [button2 setHighlighted:YES];
    }
```

But the problem is that I cannot get button2 in the same row with button1...All the time used button2 in last row...Any suggestions ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set tag property in Interface Builder for your buttons, let's say 11 for button1 and 12 for button2
2. get your button2 with the tag

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonTouchIn:(id)sender{
       if ([sender tag] == 11){
           UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
           UIButton* button2 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:12];
           [button2 setHighlighted:YES];
       }
   }
   ```

I edited this code on my PC, so there could be errors

Comment: @Jim, after a second look, I think the line `if (sender == self.button1)` should be removed, as self.button1 should be the button1 in the last cell(in order of created time). How do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method. Tag your button with a specific tag let's assume 11 for button 1 and 12 for button 2. And In an IBACtion write this code to get the cell

```
- (IBAction) btn1Tapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

UITableiewCell *cell = [[btn superview] superview];

//Now you can get the button with tag no 12

UIButton *btn2 = [cell viewWithTag:12];

[btn setHighlighted:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks...Works...One more question...I need to setHighlighet:NO when i drag my finger outside and so one...So I should override four methods ? like TouchIn, TouchDragOutside, TouchDragInside,Touch Up...

Comment: you can implement touchDown and touch up methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well with the lil info provided i can guess the problem as follows:

1. You are reusing your cells in uitable view
2. Probably assigning self.button2 in your cellforrowatindex delegate method

So the last button is getting highlighted. You should create a view controller for your tableview cell and write IBactions for the button press events in that view controller. This way every action on button goes to a seperate viewcontroller.

Let me know if this hint is useful or if you need more directions.

Comment: 1) Right, 2) @synthesize button2; Button2 and Button1 is an UIButtons, which I unite with my Buttons in xib...And yes, your hint useful and I need more inf...Thanks..